# How can I simulate a group conversation in the Bot Framework emulator?

Tags: botframework

In the Bot Framework Emulator, how can I create a group with more than one user, and switch between the users? In botframework-emulator-3.5.23 I see an "Add user" option but I don't see a way to switch between the users.

Answer (score 2):

Try with an older version of the emulator, such as version 3.0. 
For now, it has more options including the ability to switch between users.